# How can I bind mutually exclusive MenuItems with Mutually exclusive radio buttons in user control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a Mainwindow with a mutually exclusive set of menu items. These menu items move a user control over three column positions in a grid. The user control has three mutually exclusive radio buttons that also move the user control over three column positions. Currently, the menu items set the user controls position independently of the radio buttons in the user control and vis-versa. What I want to do is bind each menu item with the respective radio button. For example, if the Left Position radio button is selected, I want to have the left position menu item checked and vis-versa. How can I bind the radio buttons to their respective menu items?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <!-- Declaratively create an instance of MainViewViewModel -->
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <uc:UserControl1 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="{Binding Position}"/>        
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Position">
            <MenuItem 
                local:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="groupMenuBarPosition" 
                Header="Left Postion" 
                x:Name="leftMenuItem"
                IsChecked="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsCheckable="True"/>
            <MenuItem 
                local:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="groupMenuBarPosition"
                Header="Middle Postion"
                x:Name="middleMenuItem"
                IsChecked="{Binding Middle, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsCheckable="True" />
            <MenuItem
                local:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="groupMenuBarPosition"
                Header="Right Postion"
                x:Name="rightMenuItem"
                IsChecked="{Binding Right, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsCheckable="True" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Extensions.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
public class MenuItemExtensions : DependencyObject
{
    public static MenuItem currentselect;

    public static Dictionary<MenuItem, String> ElementToGroupNames = new Dictionary<MenuItem, String>();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GroupName",
                                     typeof(String),
                                     typeof(MenuItemExtensions),
                                     new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty, OnGroupNameChanged));

    public static void SetGroupName(MenuItem element, String value)
    {
        element.SetValue(GroupNameProperty, value);
    }

    public static String GetGroupName(MenuItem element)
    {
        return element.GetValue(GroupNameProperty).ToString();
    }

    private static void OnGroupNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Add an entry to the group name collection
        var menuItem = d as MenuItem;

        if (menuItem != null)
        {
            String newGroupName = e.NewValue.ToString();
            String oldGroupName = e.OldValue.ToString();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newGroupName))
            {
                //Removing the toggle button from grouping
                RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(menuItem);
            }
            else
            {
                //Switching to a new group
                if (newGroupName != oldGroupName)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oldGroupName))
                    {
                        //Remove the old group mapping
                        RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(menuItem);
                    }
                    ElementToGroupNames.Add(menuItem, e.NewValue.ToString());
                    menuItem.Checked += MenuItemChecked;
                    menuItem.Unchecked += MenuItemUnchecked;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(MenuItem checkBox)
    {
        ElementToGroupNames.Remove(checkBox);
        checkBox.Checked -= MenuItemChecked;
        checkBox.Unchecked -= MenuItemUnchecked;
    }

    private static void MenuItemUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;

        if (currentselect != null)
        {
            if (currentselect == menuItem && currentselect.GetValue(GroupNameProperty).ToString() == GetGroupName(menuItem))
            {
                menuItem.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    static void MenuItemChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
        currentselect = menuItem;
        foreach (var item in ElementToGroupNames)
        {
            if (item.Key != menuItem && item.Value == GetGroupName(menuItem))
            {
                item.Key.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfApp1
{
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _position = 1;
    }

    private int _position;
    private bool _left;
    private bool _middle;
    private bool _right;

    public bool Left
    {
        get
        {
            return _left;
        }
        set
        {
            _left = value;
            if (_left) { Position = 0; }                
        }
    }
    public bool Middle
    {
        get
        {
            return _middle;
        }
        set
        {
            _middle = value;
            if (_middle) { Position = 1; }
        }
    }
    public bool Right
    {
        get
        {
            return _right;
        }
        set
        {
            _right = value;
            if (_right) { Position = 2; }
        }
    }

    public int Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _position;
        }
        set
        {
            _position = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="positionUC"
         Background="Aqua">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
    <RadioButton 
        GroupName="groupPosition"
        IsChecked="{Binding Left}">
        <TextBlock Text="Left Position"/>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton 
        GroupName="groupPosition"
        IsChecked="{Binding Middle}">        
        <TextBlock Text="Middle Position"/>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton 
        GroupName="groupPosition"
        IsChecked="{Binding Right}">
        <TextBlock Text="Right Position"/>
    </RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

revised MainWindowViemModel.cs

```
using MvvmFoundation.Wpf;

namespace WpfApp1
{
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Middle = true;
    }

    private int _position;
    private bool _left;
    private bool _middle;
    private bool _right;

    public bool Left
    {
        get
        {
            return _left;
        }
        set
        {
            _left = value;
            if (_left) 
            { 
                Position = 0;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("Left");
            }                
        }
    }

    public bool Middle
    {
        get
        {
            return _middle;
        }
        set
        {
            _middle = value;
            if (_middle) 
            { 
                Position = 1;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("Middle");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Right
    {
        get
        {
            return _right;
        }
        set
        {
            _right = value;
            if (_right) 
            { Position = 2;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("Right");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _position;
        }
        set
        {
            _position = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("Position");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There are three basic ways for bindings to not work: you didn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (i.e. no event); you implemented INPC but didn't actually declare your class as such (i.e. no `: INotifyPropertyChanged` in the class declaration); you implemented INPC but didn't raise the event. The third one is your error here. Your `Left`, `Middle`, and `Right` properties don't raise the `PropertyChanged` event when they are modified.

Comment: For future reference: you should work harder to create a real [mcve]. The `UserControl` here is pure red herring, as is the menu and its attached property. All you really needed was a view model with the three booleans, and a command to rotate through them, then a window with three radio buttons grouped together and a button to execute the command.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and steering me in the right direction. I was able to get it working. Here is what I did: Added MvvmFoundation project to my solution and added reference to it. Then I hooked in 'ObservableObject' as my base for my Viewmodel. I added 'RaisePropertyChanged' change events to 'Left', 'Middle' and 'Right'. I added the revised viewmodel above. I'm sure things can be further simplified as you suggest.